# SQLite Select query gives no errors but does not display results

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt4

Basically what i want to do is return entries from a database based on the user's input and display the records in PyQt4's textBrowser widget.

This is the code:

```
    def url_search(self):
        self.browserUrl.append("Look") \\ for testing reasons, works.
        items = []
        for index in range(self.listUrl.count()):
             items.append(self.listUrl.item(index))
             conn = sqlite3.connect(directory + '\\CyberConan Databases\\CB Database\\Google Chrome\\Chrome Artifacts.db')
        for kw in items:
            self.browserUrl.append("it is") \\for testing reasons, works
            x = str(kw)
            for row in conn.execute("SELECT * FROM urls WHERE ID LIKE ? OR URL LIKE ? OR Title LIKE ? "
                                "OR Visit_Count LIKE ? OR Typed_Count LIKE ?;",
                                ("'%"+x+"%'", "'%"+x+"%'", "'%"+x+"%'", "'%"+x+"%'", "'%+x+%'")):
                 self.browserUrl.append("working") \\ for testing reasons, does not work
                 self.browserUrl.append(str(row[0]))
                 self.browserUrl.append(str(row[1]))
                 self.browserUrl.append(str(row[2]))
                 self.browserUrl.append(str(row[3]))
                 self.browserUrl.append("working man!") \\ for testing reasons, does not work
                 self.browserUrl.append(str(row[4]))
                 self.browserUrl.append(str(row[5]))
```

So the user would press a Button and this function runs. The only output im getting is:

> Look
>
> it is

This output is occurring every time the button is pressed. All the naming is correct. I get no errors. The table does contain what the user is searching for, so there should be output. Note that "it is" appears for as many kw there are in items.

(This is for a graduation project)

Comment: I don't have any experience with PyQt so I'm going to ignore the fact that large amount of the syntax is not valid in Python because you say it runs without error. But `for row in conn.execute("SELECT...`; queries are executed through the [cursor](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) not the connection.

Comment: @roganjosh the cursor is used when adding or modifying a database.
I a selecting from it, so it does not need a cursor.

Comment: Well you can also select from the database using cursor. Then you would use something like `cursor.fetchall()` to get the result. Since things are getting appended to the list but nothing from the query, perhaps the best place to start would be to see what is being returned from your query?

Comment: @roganjosh Tried that. the problem seems to be that the For loop is not even being executed. meaning:
1- that the select statement is not returning any data. thus the issue would be with the syntax of the SELECT statement.
2- there is an issue with the DB connection and execution.
I think it is the first one.

Comment: @NadeemAli. Why aren't you using [QSqlTableModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsqltablemodel.html)? Dumping the results into a text-browser is really crude, and unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @ekhumoro First off, thank you for your edits and input.
Secondly, I want to display it in a text browser because i will be manipulating the data so it comes out in CSV.

Answer (score 1):

okay so I found out what the problem was.

First: the parsing of the string in the select statement was not done correctly.

Second: when I was returning the items from the list, i was returning their "locations" and not the strings themselves.

This is the solved code for anyone who may have run into a similar issue:

```
    def url_search(self):
         items = []
         for index in range(self.listUrl.count()):
              thing = self.listUrl.item(index)
              items.append(thing.text())
         conn = sqlite3.connect(directory + '\\CyberConan Databases\\CB Database\\Google Chrome\\Chrome Artifacts.db')
         for kw in items:
              x = str(kw)
              for row in conn.execute("SELECT * FROM urls WHERE ID LIKE ? OR URL LIKE ? OR Title LIKE ? "
                                "OR Visit_Count LIKE ? OR Typed_Count LIKE ?;",
                                ("%"+x+"%", "%"+x+"%", "%"+x+"%", "%"+x+"%", "%"+x+"%")):
                   self.browserUrl.append(str(row))
    conn.close()
```